# I have written following code wont get it work because after my query i dont know what to write

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

                SPList customerList = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
                if (customerList != null)
                {
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query =
                        string.Format(
                            "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ProductNumber' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith></Where>");

                    query.RowLimit = 10;

                    SPListItemCollection items = customerList.GetItems(query);



                    foreach (SPListItem customer in items)
                    {


                        TextBox_Name.Text = customer["Title"].ToString();
                        TextBox_ProdNum.Text = customer["ProductNumber"].ToString();
                        TextBox_Color.Text = customer["Color"].ToString();
                        TextBox_ListPrice.Text = customer["ListPrice"].ToString();
                        TextBox_MoreInfo.Text = customer["More Info"] != null
                                                    ? customer["More Info"].ToString()
                                                    : string.Empty;
```

Comment: they didnt help

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you want to achive? so far your querying a list and populating some controls with the list values.

Comment: hi! i want to update column in an list true textboxes , my problem is that , all the items that i have in my list get updated

Comment: First of all, that code should not compile (since the string.Format needs at least two parameters).
Second, that query might return a collection of SPListItems which if you iterate to update will obviously update ALL the elements in the SPListItemCollection

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am just stupid but you aren't formatting any variable into the CAML statement at all.

```
// Add the variable to the string.Format
query.Query = string.Format("<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ProductNumber' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith></Where>", myVariable);
```